# Why does an NSObject have to be initialized before its' .class-property is readable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

If I say for example:

```
UIImageView *imageView;
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", imageView.class);
```

It will log `UIImageView` as expected.

---

Now, if I instead write the code in a way where the UIImageView's `.class` property is used in allocating the object (which is declared/defined as a UIImageView on line 0), it will log `(null)`

```
UIImageView *myImageView;
myImageView = [[myImageView.class alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", myImageView.class);//logs (null)
```

---

Even if I hard cast the object to a UIImageView whilst reading its' `.class` value, when I then go to log said class value later on, I still get `(null)`

```
UIImageView *myImageView;
myImageView = [[((UIImageView *)myImageView).class alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", myImageView.class);//logs (null)
```

Comment: `[[myImageView.class alloc] init]` is the same as `[[nil alloc] init]` which does nothing.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question really is, why is it `nil` even though I've cast it as `UIImageView *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you didn't initialize you `myImageView` yet  , you the `.class` return `nil` to you.

```
UIImageView *myImageView;
myImageView = [[myImageView.class alloc] init]; // didn't initialize myImageView
NSLog(@"%@", myImageView.class);//logs (null)
```

so if you want do Something Like that :

```
myImageView = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIImage") alloc] init];

NSLog(@"%@", myImageView.class);//logs (UIImage)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a great way of setting the class for the allocation for what I'm trying to do (involving CLANG shortcuts)

Comment: I was not aware of `NSClassFromString`